# Is it possible to use Angular to communicate with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, frontend, backend

Can I use MySQL, PHP and Apache to communicate with my front end which is built with JavaScript (Angular)?

Is this a problem since PHP and JavaScript are both web programming languages?

Thanks in advance, I'm sort of new to all of this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Angular `$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to make calls to your php backend.

Make sure you send json from php to angular. (use `json_encode()`)

Comment: I'm not sure what any of that means to be honest. I'm a noob with all of this.

Comment: His answer was pretty simple, so you need to elaborate on what it is you don't understand. $http makes an ajax request to PHP, PHP makes an sql request to MySQL. MySQL response with data to PHP, PHP parses that data into JSON, PHP then returns this data to $http. If you're stuck on one of these terms you need to do more research